# what is [...] in proof general and why can't I delete it

Tags: coq, proof-general

When I try and copy paste proof code, sometimes a [...] will show up (even though I did not copy anything of the kind) and I cannot delete it. I have to undo the copy in order to get rid of it. What does this mean?

Thanks.

Comment: I have not encountered this issue before... What version of PG are you using? Can you reproduce the error unconditionally, or does it arise purely by luck?

Comment: Do you use [company-coq](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq)? if yes, maybe this is just the [code folding feature](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq/blob/master/img/folding.gif)?

Comment: I can't manage to reproduce it, but it has happened to me twice before. It always happens when I am copy pasting code from one proof into a different proof that is still in progress, but unfortunately I cannot give you more details than that. My version of PG is 4.5 and my version of emacs is 24.3.

Comment: @ErikMD that's exactly what it is! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, the occurrences of `[…]` correspond here to the [code folding feature](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq/blob/master/img/folding.gif) of [company-coq](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq).

To toggle the visibility of a block (starting with a brace, e.g.

```
Goal True /\ True.
split.
{ […]
```

or starting with a bullet, e.g.

```
Goal True /\ True.
split.
- idtac. […]
```

), you can just move the point to the opening symbol `{` or `-`, and press <kbd>RET</kbd>

Otherwise, to "unfold" all blocks of the ambient buffer, you can do:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>company-coq-features/code-folding-reset-to-initial-state</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>